# Play framework: Serving assets based on session

Tags: java, playframework, assets, playframework-2.6

I am trying to serve assets in play framework based on current user session.
for resolving this I use this snippet:

```
    public Result logo() {
    ApiDescriptor apiDes = sessionManager.getApiDescriptor(ctx());
    String imagename = apiDes.getApiKey() + ".png";
    final play.api.Application application = Play.unsafeApplication();
    if (application.isDev()) {
        return ok(application.getFile("/public/spa/images/brokerage/logo/" + imagename));
    } else
        return ok(application.getFile("../../../public/spa/images/brokerage/logo/" + imagename));
}
```

this works properly for using with `sbt run` and `sbt start` but when I am using `sbt dist`, I receive this error:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: ?????.png
    at akka.stream.impl.io.FileSource$$anon$1.preStart(IOSources.scala:74)...
```

I use `Assets` controller for resolving this problem:

```
public Action<AnyContent> logo() {
    ApiDescriptor apiDes = sessionManager.getApiDescriptor(ctx());
    String imagename = apiDes.getApiKey() + ".png";
    return assets.at("/public/spa/images/brokerage/logo", imagename, true);
}
```

but session is not available when returning `Action<AnyContent>` :

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.]]
```